# C# string to SqlDateTime: how to set format for recognition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, locale, sqldatetime

I need to use

```
SqlDateTime.Parse(val)
```

where val is a string such as " 23.3.1992 00:00:00 ".

The string is in European format, that is, day precedes month. However Parse wants "American" format. How I can tell it to use particular datetime format / locale?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you not have a `DateTime` instance to pass in to the database? Why use strings at all for this?

Comment: Why not use something totally unambigious like `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` so `2013-05-29 13:38:00` then everything will know what it means.

Comment: SqlDateTime uses the InvariantCulture. When you need something different use a DateTime and its Parse overloads where you can provide a different culture or format. And then use the SqlDateTime constructor that takes a DateTime. And like the other if possible better try to use a culture independent string format if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
string val = "23.12.1992 00:00:00";

// Parse exactly from your input string to the native date format.
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(val, "dd.M.yyyy hh:mm:ss", null);

// Part to SqlDateTime then            
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime dtSql = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Parse(dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

This could be done in one statement, but just separated for illustration.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried DateTime instead of SQLDateTime

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(val); 
String s = d.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
string valInEuropean = "23.3.1992 00:00:00";
DateTime dateInEuropean = DateTime.Parse(valInEuropean);
string valInAmerican = dateInEuropean.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ww");
```

Comment: This will only work if his culture is already set to European, otherwise the DateTime.Parse call will fail.

Comment: euhh yes, but it does or not?

Answer (score 0):

For converting a string to datetime object when the format is known(in this case )
use

```
DateTime dwweek = DateTime.ParseExact("23.3.1992 00:00:00", "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```